# How to darken the background view while custom popup is showing in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Achieving  :[image]

Requirement:
[image]I am showing custom popup to the user at perticular condition but I am not able to darken the popup background like when display alert is coming it's background screen is dark. Please suggest any idea. Thanks in advance.

Here is the sample code :

```
     <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <StackLayout Grid.Row = "0" HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand" VeticalOptions = "FillAndExpand">
    <Label Text = "Sample" />   
    <Label Text = "Sample" /> 
    <Label Text = "Sample" /> 
    <Label Text = "Sample" /> 
 </StackLayout>
 <controls:SampleCustomPopup x:Name="DialACallControl" Grid.Row="0" IsVisible="{Binding IsPopUpToShow}" Grid.RowSpan="2"        
          VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>  
  </Grid>
```

Here is the code CustomPopup code:

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="7">
    <Frame BackgroundColor="White" OutlineColor="#f5f5f5" HasShadow="True">
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Image Source="phone.png">
                    <Image.HeightRequest>
                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                            <OnIdiom.Phone>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="25" Android="30" WinPhone="30" />
                            </OnIdiom.Phone>
                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="35" Android="40" WinPhone="40" />
                            </OnIdiom.Tablet>
                        </OnIdiom>
                    </Image.HeightRequest>
                </Image>
                <Label Text="{Binding PhoneNumber}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="#323232" FontFamily="Avenir Book">
                    <Label.FontSize>
                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments ="x:Double" Phone ="15" Tablet ="20"/>
                    </Label.FontSize>
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Text="Call" Grid.Column="0" TextColor="White" BorderRadius="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#f2c646" BorderColor="Black" StyleId="phagspab" >

                    <Button.FontSize>
                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments ="x:Double" Phone ="15" Tablet ="20"/>
                    </Button.FontSize>
                    <Button.HeightRequest>
                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                            <OnIdiom.Phone>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="30" Android="40" WinPhone="30" />
                            </OnIdiom.Phone>
                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="40" Android="50" WinPhone="40" />
                            </OnIdiom.Tablet>
                        </OnIdiom>
                    </Button.HeightRequest>
                </Button>
                <Button Text="Cancel" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="White" BorderRadius="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#323232" BorderColor="Black" StyleId="phagspab" >
                    <Button.FontSize>
                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments ="x:Double" Phone ="15" Tablet ="20"/>
                    </Button.FontSize>
                    <Button.HeightRequest>
                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                            <OnIdiom.Phone>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="30" Android="40" WinPhone="30" />
                            </OnIdiom.Phone>
                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="40" Android="50" WinPhone="40" />
                            </OnIdiom.Tablet>
                        </OnIdiom>
                    </Button.HeightRequest>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the custom pop up background you can give  BackgroundColor="##60000000"  which gives a pop up like effect. I have explained this in details in [PopUp to contains other controls like DateTime Picker,dropdownlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44643116/popup-to-contains-other-controls-like-datetime-picker-dropdownlist/44643923?noredirect=1#comment76292985_44643923)
You can also check my repo github.com/RenjithPr90/DemoPopUp
Thanks

Comment: Thanks Renjith, I have tried what you have suggested but it's background color is show surrounding of popup only but we need to dark the total background behind the popup.

Comment: Can you show what exactly you need. By adding BackgroundColor="##60000000" you will get transparent background with light black color effect. If you need complete black give black color instead.

Comment: Hi renjith, I have update my question with images after applying background color to the popup what I have getting and what my requirement.

Comment: Can you check whether this repo is useful for you  github.com/RenjithPr90/DemoPopUp

Comment: Yes renjit, I have follow your code but we didn't get the required result.

Comment: If you share your project we might try to help

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to do is use a `BoxView` as you background and overlay your pop up over the top.

The `BoxView` will be used to create the dark background. 
This can be achieved by setting the background color of the `BoxView` to black and setting the `Opacity` to about 0.5.

Once you have the background done you simply have to overlay your popup view over the top of the `BoxView`. This can be achieved by a few Layouts (`RelativeLayout`, `AbsoluteLayout`, `Grid`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is the right solution/approach but it will do the job done.

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}" BackgroundColor="#80000000" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="TAP ME" Clicked="Handle_Clicked" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
</Grid>
```

Here you can see I am just binding the visibility of the StackLayout to `IsLoading`.

Inside .cs page, implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Make sure to set BindingContext `IsLoading` value according to the dialog. Below code will explain my logic better than me.

```
public partial class TestAppsPage : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TestAppsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }

    async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        IsLoading = true;
        var answer = await DisplayAlert("Mr Title", "This is a dummy", "OK", "Cancel");
        if (answer || !answer)
            IsLoading = false;

    }



    private bool isLoading;
    public bool IsLoading
    {
        get
        {
            return isLoading;
        }

        set
        {
            isLoading = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsLoading");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));

        }
    }
}
```

Tested on an Android device and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In XAML, try this code. ([Referred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40044671/7196681))

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollView>
        <!-- Insert your page content in here -->
    </ScrollView>

    <ContentView IsVisible="false" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="LightGray" Opacity="0.5" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="LogOutContentView">
        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="false" x:Name="LogoutProgressIndicator" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </ContentView>
</Grid>
```

You can put the colour you want for `BackgroundColor` and set the `Opacity` as required. (0.5 will make it 50% opaque)

In your code, you can show the progress as follows.

```
LogOutContentView.IsVisible = true;
LogoutProgressIndicator.IsRunning = true;
```

And when done, you can set the above two values to `false`.